# Prove that $(((f_{*})^*)^*)_{*}: P(P(P(P(A))))\rightarrow P(P(P(P(B))))$ is injective

Tags: functions, logic

Let $f^*$ be the image of $f$ and $f_{*}$ be the preimage of $f$. How can I prove (step by step, using definitions of images and preimages) that if $f: A \rightarrow B$ is injective, then $$(((f_{*})^*)^*)_{*}: P(P(P(P(A))))\rightarrow P(P(P(P(B))))$$ is injective?

Comment: Guess it's easier to prove that $f$ injective $\Rightarrow$ $f^*$ injective and $f_*$ injective. The result will follow.

Comment: @lisyarus I think it would be harder to prove that claim, because it's not true ($f^*$ need not be injective).

Comment: @AlexKruckman Oh, of course, thank you. I meant what's in your excellent answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Hint:* Prove the following claims:

1. If $f$ is injective, then $f_*$ is injective.
2. If $f$ is injective, then $f^*$ is surjective.
3. If $f$ is surjective, then $f_*$ is surjective.
4. If $f$ is surjective, then $f^*$ is injective.

Now $f$ injective $\Rightarrow$ $f_*$ injective $\Rightarrow$ $(f_*)^*$ surjective $\Rightarrow$ $((f_*)^*)^*$ injective $\Rightarrow$ $(((f_*)^*)^*)_*$ injective.

By 1, then 2, then 4, then 1. (Ok, so you don't have to prove 3 if you don't want to).